# Create a record from related "belongs to" route. Assertion failed: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'group' record to this relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a new "student" from within the "group" route. The "student" belongs to the group. True to form, as soon as you want to do anything different to the very straightforward examples, things become a total mystery - I'd appreciate some help!

"Students" belong to a "Group". From within the "group" route, I want to create new students for that group. So, in my "groups/:group_ID" route's controller, I have the following "saveStudent" action...

```
        saveStudent: function(){
            var self = this;
            var classID = parseInt(this.get('model.id'));
            var name = this.get('studentName');    //studentName from input box

            var newStudent = this.store.createRecord('student', {
                name: name,
                group: classID
            });
            newStudent.save();
        }
```

This fails with

> Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'group' record to this relationship

If I don't have the kv pair:

```
group: classID
```

the new student is created as expected, but of course I have nothing on the relationship.

I don't know how to do this in the context of the relationship. Do I need to update the "group" model myself, or can Ember take care of this for me?

I'm using Ember-CLI in case there's any difference. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the record, and not the id.  Assuming `model` is the group, you would do

```
   saveStudent: function(){
        var self = this;
        var group = this.get('model');
        var name = this.get('studentName');    //studentName from input box

        var newStudent = this.store.createRecord('student', {
            name: name,
            group: group
        });
        newStudent.save();
    }
```

And Ember-Data (remember, Ember and Ember Data are two different products) won't automatically hook up the student on the group, assuming you have a `hasMany` on the group of students.  You can just manually add it to that group (I'd recommend after the save).